Player swinging slowly with Distance joint in Unity 2D
I’m making a grappling hook with a distance joint in my 2D platformer game. However, the player is supposed to swing fast when they hook onto an object, but instead, they are swinging slowly.
I tried creating another sprite and adding the same Grappling Hook script to it. When I pressed play, the sprite swung fast as intended. The player’s and the sprite’s components, such as Rigidbody, distance joint, and line renderer, are the same, except I didn’t include the PlayerController script in the other sprite. Therefore, I think something is wrong with my PlayerController script that prevents the player from swinging fast, because I removed PlayerController script from the player and It worked, but PlayerController script is very useful. I also noticed that player swings fast if I replace Velocity with AddForce, but the player's movement is like on the ice.
Here's the script of the player (With Velocity):
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Status
    [Header("Status")]
    [SerializeField] public float speed;
    [SerializeField] public float regularSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce;

    // Movement Mechanics
    [Header("Movement Mechanics")]
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float move;
    [SerializeField] private bool isOnGround;
    [SerializeField] private Transform groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;

    [SerializeField] private bool isMovingLeft;
    [SerializeField] private bool isMovingRight;

    public bool canMove;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        speed = regularSpeed;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Check for keyboard inputs
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            MoveLeft();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            MoveRight();
        }
        else if (!isMovingLeft && !isMovingRight)
        {
            StopMoving();
        }

        // Set direction based on button states
        if (isMovingLeft)
        {
            MoveLeft();
        }
        else if (isMovingRight)
        {
            MoveRight();
        }

        // Jump when the Jump button is pressed and player is grounded
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded() && canMove)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce));
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && rb.velocity.y > 10)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Update Rigidbody velocity based on move direction
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(speed * move, rb.velocity.y, 0);
    }

    // Button press handlers
    public void OnLeftButtonDown() => isMovingLeft = true;
    public void OnLeftButtonUp() => isMovingLeft = false;
    public void OnRightButtonDown() => isMovingRight = true;
    public void OnRightButtonUp() => isMovingRight = false;

    public void MoveLeft()
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
        move = -1;
    }

    public void MoveRight()
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        move = 1;
    }

    public void Jump()
    {
        if (isGrounded() && canMove)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce));
        }
    }

    public void StopMoving()
    {
        move = 0;
    }

    private bool isGrounded()
    {
        return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);
    }
}

Here's the video of player:
https://youtu.be/LKtuEjaY_KM
And here's the video of another sprite:
https://youtube.com/shorts/CguW2uXhBv8?feature=share

What is the PlayerController script?

Well using this rb.velocity = new Vector3(speed * move, rb.velocity.y, 0); overwrites any other changes on your velocity so this is fighting against the swing .. one way would he to have a state check and disable that line while you are swinging
